# Why does this swift code keep saying "fatal error: Index out of range"?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, parsing, debugging

Its been like 2 days now trying to figure why this code keeps giving me the error of out of index when clearly its within range. I am trying append arrayOfCominedStyles[i] with images downloaded from heroku server.

Below is the code, thanks!

```
var arrayOfCombinedStyles = [[UIImage](), [UIImage](), [UIImage](), [UIImage]()]

        let parseQuery = PFQuery(className: "Styles")

        parseQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)

        parseQuery.whereKey("status", equalTo: "READY")

        parseQuery.limit = 1

        parseQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in

            if let objects = objects {

                for obj in objects {

                    for var i = 0; i < self.arrayOfCombinedStyles.count; i++ {

                        for var ii = 0; ii < arrayOfClientCount[i]; ii++ {

                          let imageData = obj["\(self.strr[i])\(ii+1)"] as! PFFile

                           imageData.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) in

                            if error != nil {

                                //error here

                            }else {

                                if let data = data {

                                    if let image = UIImage(data: data){

                                        self.arrayOfCombinedStyles[i].append(image)

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                           })

                        }
                    }

                }
            }else {


                //error, you did not submit any


            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you put an exception breakpoint to figure out which line is giving this exception?

Comment: Yes, the self.arrayOfCombinedStyles[i].append(image) line

Comment: Is there a possibility that there are two `arrayOfCombinedStyles`? The local one is initialized as above but instance property one (`self.arrayOfCombinedStyles`) is not

Comment: I thought of that too. I tried changing the name by adding an 's' at the end to make it very unique but still, the same result.